# _mm_mul_ps won't multiply 10001 with 10001 correctly but works fine for 10000 with 10000

Tags: c, x86, multiplication, simd, sse

I have a very simple program to multiply four numbers. It works
fine when each of them is 10000 but does not if I change them to 10001. The result is off by one.

I compiled the program with `gcc -msse2 main_sse.c -o sse` on both AMD Opteron and Intel Xeon and get the same result on both machines.

I would appreciate any help. Couldn't find anything online on this topic.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main(){

    float x[4], y[4], temp[4]; int i;  __m128 X, Y, result;
 
    for(i=0; i < 4; i++) { x[i] = 10000; y[i] = 10000; }

    X = _mm_load_ps(&x[0]);  Y = _mm_load_ps(&y[0]);  
    result = _mm_mul_ps(X,Y); _mm_store_ps(&temp[0], result);

    for(i=0; i < 4; i++) { x[i] = 10001; y[i] = 10001; }

    X = _mm_load_ps(&x[0]);  Y = _mm_load_ps(&y[0]);  
    result = _mm_mul_ps(X,Y); _mm_store_ps(&temp[0], result);
}
```

Comment: Note that as well as @Mark's correct answer below, you are very lucky that your code even runs, since you have no guarantee that x, y and temp are 16 byte aligned.

Answer (score 11):

You are running into the limits of precision of  [IEEE 32 bit floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).

There are only 23 bits of fractional mantissa plus an implied '1' at the beginning.
So the largest integer that can be exactly represented is 2<sup>24</sup> = 16777216

You would need 27 bits to exactly represent the product of 10001*10001 = 100020001.

Once you go above 2<sup>24</sup>, you only get the nearest even integer.

Once you go above 2<sup>25</sup>, you only get the nearest multiple of 4.

And so on.